# laravel query when compare with float column can`t get the right result

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, lumen

the odd column is float type in MySQL

1.`$query->where("odd", ">", 0.3);` odd less than `0.3` data will be query out

2.`$query->whereRaw("odd > 0.3");` this one return the right result
so why?

I try whereRaw can work right with float column

Comment: `$query->where('odd', '>', '0.3');` try out. But your queries look fine. What is the data type of the `odd` column?